# How to compile linux kernel subdirectory?

Tags: linux, makefile, build, kernel

I want to compile linux kernel subdirectory just like this:

```
make M=drivers/staging/comedi/
```

Unfortunately when I do this I get this error:

```
  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

Makefile:648: include/config/auto.conf: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
make: *** [Makefile:719: include/config/auto.conf] Błąd 1
```

It may be fixed by this command:

```
make oldconfig
```

After executing it, I have to press enter for 2 minutes to select the default options everywhere, and then I get this error anyway:

```
  AR      drivers/staging/comedi//built-in.a
WARNING: Symbol version dump "Module.symvers" is missing.
         Modules may not have dependencies or modversions.
  MODPOST drivers/staging/comedi//Module.symvers
/bin/sh: scripts/mod/modpost: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:111: drivers/staging/comedi//Module.symvers] Błąd 127
make: *** [Makefile:1701: modules] Błąd 2
```

I have seen many times in the videos people just building a subdirectory with one `make M=somedir` command. Why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: You need to build the kernel itself (with `make`) before building modules will be accessible.

Comment: Also, I could swear there's a target for choosing all default options (`make defaultconfig`?) that would get rid of the "press[ing] enter for 2 minutes".